# Twitter App using C# using OAuth token

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to get a workaround so that i don't have to press the Allow button everytime when I make use of the Twitter API.

```
if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
        {
            //Redirect the user to Twitter for authorization.
            //Using oauth_callback for local testing.
            oAuth.CallBackUrl = "http://localhost";
            Response.Redirect(oAuth.AuthorizationLinkGet());
        }
```

In the code example above i just get a OAuth token but Twitter asks me to confirm that i want to allow access. Is there a workaround so that i don't have to Accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the allow step is quite out of your hands.  It would be potentially malicious to let a web site authorize a token request on behalf of a user.